# Mysterious bit mismatch for VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am making a 32 bit register with port and generic mapping. For some reason it says that the target signal Qt has 31 bits, while the input has 32 bits. Makes no sense right now. I looked through everything, and could not find how the Qt could be anything else than 32 bits since I declared the signal as `signal Qt: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);`Any help is appreciated thanks.

I isolated the error line `Qt <= D;` and it still threw an exception. Down below is my minimally reproducible example.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.math_real.log2;
use ieee.math_real.ceil;


entity my_rege is
   generic (N: INTEGER:= 32);
    port ( clock, resetn: in std_logic;
           E, sclr: in std_logic; -- sclr: Synchronous clear
             D: in std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);
           Q: out std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0));
end my_rege;

architecture Behavioral of my_rege is

    signal Qt: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    
begin
                    Qt <= D;


    Q <= Qt;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: @Russell It was in the TCL. width mismatch in assignment; target has 32 bits, source has 31 bits at `Qt <= D;`

Comment: This doesn't tell the whole story. `qt <= d` and `Q <= Qt` Will only work when `N` is 32. The error looks like you set N to 31.

Comment: @Tricky Exactly what happened, I referenced this in the top file within my design. The integer was defined to be 31 in the component not the entity listed above. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Did not realize that I had `N: INTEGER:= 31` in the top file. When I changed the definition to `N: INTEGER:= 32` the error disappeared. Sloppy coding on my part. I don't know why the tcl referenced this in the register file and not the top(lapfn) file. Is this because VHDL is written top down after port mapping, and it assumed the component from the top was the true bit-size?

```
entity LAPfn is
  Port (resetn, clock, sclr, lap_db: in std_logic;
        lap_select: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0); 
        Data_in:    in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        Lap_bits:   out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        zlap:       out std_logic;
        cout: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
        
end LAPfn;

architecture Behavioral of LAPfn is

component my_rege
   generic (N: INTEGER:= 31);
    port ( clock, resetn: in std_logic;
           E, sclr: in std_logic; -- sclr: Synchronous clear
           D: in std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);
           Q: out std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0));
end component;
```

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.math_real.log2;
use ieee.math_real.ceil;

entity my_rege is
generic (N: INTEGER:= 32);
    port ( clock, resetn: in std_logic;
           E, sclr: in std_logic; -- sclr: Synchronous clear
             D: in std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);
           Q: out std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0));
end my_rege;

architecture Behavioral of my_rege is

    signal Qt: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    
begin

                    Qt <= D;

    Q <= Qt;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: This is where the error should appear. It appears where the line is evaluated.

Comment: Neither your question nor your answer illustrates your problem nor it's solution. Such would require actual component instantiation. What is the *subclass code* of which you write?

Comment: Rewrite it so that the internals take their width from the generic. Or at the very least, ASSERT the correct relationship between generics and internals SEVERITY FAILURE.

Comment: @user16145658 I meant subclass by referring to the register that is being port mapped. I changed my solution accordingly to illustrate my solution more thoroughly.